# Template declared to match element, but never triggered

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<docs>
    <biblos>
        <texto xmlns="http://www.aranzadi.es/namespace/contenido/biblos/texto" idioma="spa">
            <parrafo>
                <en-origen estilo-fuente="cursiva">This is cursive text.</en-origen>
            </parrafo>
        </texto>
    </biblos>
</docs>
```

and the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <section class="chapter">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="docs"/>
                </section>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="docs">
        <div class="chapter">
        <xsl:text>Docs Block</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="biblos"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="biblos">
      <xsl:text>biblos block</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="texto">
        <xsl:text>Text To Block</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="parrafo">
        <div class="para">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="parrafo">
        <span class="format-smallcaps">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="en-origen">
        <xsl:variable name="fontStyle">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./@estilo-fuente">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-style-',@estilo-fuente)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="./@format">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('format-',@format)"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <span class="{$fontStyle}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

when i run this, I'm getting the below output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<html>
   <body>
      <section class="chapter">
         <div class="chapter">Docs Blockbiblos block


                            This is cursive text.
         </div>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here the problem is, though I've declared `texto` and child nodes of it in my XSLT, it is not getting called, but the text is directly getting printed.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question (thanks for providing a complete, working example!). Often, if elements are not matched, the cause lies in missing namespaces:

You have the following in your input XML:

> ```
>  <texto xmlns="http://www.aranzadi.es/namespace/contenido/biblos/texto" idioma="spa">
> ```

In other words, the `texto` element is in a namespace. In your XSLT you have the following:

> ```
> <xsl:template match="texto">
> ```

Since no namespace is declared for XPath (`xpath-default-namespace` on the containing `xsl:template` or `xsl:stylesheet`), this will operate on elements `texto` in no namespace, meaning, as written, it will not match `texto` from your source.

You can solve this by:

```
<xsl:transform 
    xmlns:tto="http://www.aranzadi.es/namespace/contenido/biblos/texto"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
```

and:

```
<xsl:template match="tto:texto">
```

Now your template will be matched.

Remember that element names can be in a namespace if the namespace is declared on that element, but the attributes, unless prefixes, are in no nammespace, so this solution is only required (given your example input) on matching or selecting elements.

Also, it is important to realize that prefixes do not matter, they do not need to match the prefix (or absence thereof) from the source document. What matters, is that the namespace bound to the prefix matches.

If there are child elements, in this case `parrafo` and `en-origen`, these inherit the namespace given on their parent element. So if you want to match these elements as well, you should adjust their names to `tto:paraffo` and `tto:en-origin` in patterns and XPath expressions.

Comment: Thanks @Able for this awesome explaination, this solves my doubts. Thanks Again

Comment: @user3872094: you're welcome. I noticed you accepted the answer, but then the green acceptance mark disappeared again, something not (quite) right yet?

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was consuming a 3rd party xml file and trying to write XSLT against it with a default and mulitple named namespaces.  The default was catching me out.  I put it in the XSLT declaration as "nsdef" and selected/matched on nsdef:mytag throughout and all was right with the world again. A subtle difference between XML behaviour and XSLT behaviour for default namespaces.

Comment: @Sazoocat, in XSLT the `xpath-default-namespace`attribute can be used on any element to set what namespace is the default for XPath expressions. Since XSLT is written itself in XML, rules for XML apply. What often confuses people is the the no-name namespace in XML is not also automatically the no-name namespace in your XSLT, unless you declare it such. And what then adds to the confusion is that the default namespace of unprefixed names in XPath expressions is not there same (unless you declare it such) as the default namespace for unprefixed literal result elements in your stylesheet.

Comment: Tried that, my MS.NET C# code threw an exception parsing it.  The default namespace manually applied in the XSLT file worked a treat.  I'm happy with that solution. It works and is clear to understand.